# Android field is stored as null in column after migration

Tags: android, sqlite, migration

After migration in android sqllite database, new field is stored as null and I don't know why. All I did was adding new field to Object class and create migration method where I add new column and fill all values. I can see new column and populated values in Database Inspector but when I'm adding new record, all field except new one are stored.
Object class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "organizer_item")
public class OrganizerItem {

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "organizer_item";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_DATE = "notification_date";
public static final String COLUMN_TEXT = "text";

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = COLUMN_ID)
private int id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_DATE)
private long dateTime;

@DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_TEXT)
private String text;

@DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_DATE)
private long notificationDateTime;

public OrganizerItem(){}

public OrganizerItem(long dateTime,long notificationDateTime, String text) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.text = text;
    this.notificationDateTime = notificationDateTime;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(long dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

public long getNotificationDateTime() {
    return notificationDateTime;
}

public void setNotificationDateTime(long notificationDateTime) {
    this.notificationDateTime = notificationDateTime;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

Migration:

```
   private void upgrade(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String addNotificationDateTimeQuery = ("ALTER TABLE " + OrganizerItem.TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN "
            + OrganizerItem.COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_DATE + " INTEGER");
    db.execSQL(addNotificationDateTimeQuery);
    long fiveMinAsMiliseconds = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    String initAddNotificationDateTimeQuery = ("UPDATE " + OrganizerItem.TABLE_NAME + " SET "
            + OrganizerItem.COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_DATE + " =  " + OrganizerItem.COLUMN_DATE + " - " + fiveMinAsMiliseconds);
    db.execSQL(initAddNotificationDateTimeQuery);
}
```

Database inspector screen:
[image]
Rows 11-12 were populated when I tried create records after migration.

To insert record I use:

```
private RuntimeExceptionDao<OrganizerItem, Integer> organizerItemDao = null;
```

It is populated later.

and on button click:

```
organizerItemDao.update(organizerItem);
```

orginizerItem has all field populated.Below log output before update:

```
OrganizerItem{id=0, dateTime=1654717800000, text='New Stackoverflow Test', notificationDateTime=1654717500000}
```

And screen from Database Inspector:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ormlite_config.txt file has missing configuration.
It can be found under path: res -> raw

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]